# Why all git heads are not shown on gitweb?

Tags: git

When I running following command, its showing me three `git` branches

```
me@myhost:~/myrepo$ git branch
* master
  new_branch
  third
```

However the `gitweb` is showing only two branches. Only `master` and `new_branch`.

[image]

Does it require any further configuration to do the `third` branch visible on `gitweb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a remote repository which can be explored by gitweb, and a local one.

I suppose the branch on your local repository has not been pushed on the remote one. In this case, try :

```
me@myhost:~/myrepo$ git push origin third
```

If your remote repository is called `origin` (default name), it will publish your branch as a new reference visible in the `gitweb` repository.